# Uninstall RVM, Ruby, Ruby gem and rails in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: uninstall, ruby, rails, rvm

What is the best way to remove RVM, Ruby, Ruby gem and rails in Ubuntu 12.04 ?

Comment: the more details you provide, the more it is easy to help for us. Try to provide details, how you installed them and What procedure you followed to remove them.

Comment: I want to completely remove and re install them.

Comment: This is the same details we already have. How did you installed them? What command or methods you used. And How are you trying to remove them? Add the details in the question

Comment: I installed such package using RVM, but I want to uninstalled. I used "sudo apt-get remove ruby1.9.3" command, Only rails is removed. but ruby not installed.

Answer (score 6):

Try this command:

`rvm implode`

Then follow the prompts.

Also remove any references of `rvm` you might have made in the past in your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.